# How to prove infinitely many events of ($A_n$) occur almost surely

Tags: measure-theory, independence

Let $A_1, A_2,\dots$ be a sequence of independent events with $\mathbb{P}(A_n) = p_n \in [0,1)$. Show that the following are equivalent.

a). at least one of the $A_n$'s occur almost surely.

b). infinitely many events of ($A_n$) occur almost surely.

This is how I started;
Clearly b). implies a). so take a). to be true. That is
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}\bigg(\bigcup_{n\geq1} A_n\bigg) = 1
\end{equation}
We want to prove that this implies infinitely many $A_n$ occur almost surely or that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mathbb{P}\bigg(\bigcup_{m\geq n} A_m\bigg) = 1
\end{equation}
This is equivalent to showing
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}\bigg(\bigcap_{m\geq n} A_m^c\bigg) = 1-\mathbb{P}\bigg(\bigcup_{m\geq n} A_m\bigg) =0
\end{equation}

Taking limits and using the independence of the events we have
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}\bigg(\bigcap_{m\geq 1} A_m^c\bigg) = \mathbb{P}\bigg(\bigcap_{m\geq n} A_m^c\bigg)\mathbb{P}\bigg(\bigcap_{m<n} A_m^c\bigg) = 0
\end{equation}
But,
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}\bigg(\bigcap_{m<n} A_m^c\bigg) = \prod_{m<n}\mathbb{P}(A^c_n) >0
\end{equation}
since each $P(A^c_n) \in (0,1)$. Then from above we have for any $n$
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}\bigg(\bigcap_{m\geq n} A_m^c\bigg) = 0
\end{equation}
which implies
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}\bigg(\bigcup_{m\geq n} A_m\bigg) = 1
\end{equation}
Thus
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mathbb{P}\bigg(\bigcup_{m\geq n} A_m\bigg) = 1
\end{equation}
...

...

Are there any flaws in my proof? I.e. is it ok to assume $P(A^c_n) \in (0,1)$ and that b). implies a). so therefore they're equivalent?

Comment: If $A_n$s occurs as. then $PA_n =1$.

Comment: $P(A_n) \in (0,1)$ should be replaced by $P(A_n) \in (0,1]$.   a) has been stated in an ambiguous way but what is intended is clear.

Comment: ok, perfect thanks. Forgot about that :/